# How to get clang-format working in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, clang-format

Visual Studio has [native integration for clang-format](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/clangformat-support-in-visual-studio-2017-15-7-preview-1/) since 15.7 prev1.

I'm using 15.9.9 and nicely see the configuration in the options.
[image: Visual Studio Configuration C++ Formatting]

From my understanding, as 'Google' is selected in the formatting style, it should use either my .clang-format file which is in the root of my checkout or fallback to the hard-coded configuration with name 'Google'.

However, if I format my file: Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D, my file gets formatted using Whitesmiths; which is the brace configuration of my Visual Studio formatting.

Did I forget to configure something that allows me to use clang-format or is something horribly going wrong? If it is the last one, I appreciate some debugging tips.

Comment: "By default, Visual Studio will use any existing ClangFormat file in your source tree for formatting operations. To turn this off, you can uncheck Enable ClangFormat support." - do you have ClangFormat file in your source tree?

Comment: @VTT Yes, I have a .clang-format. My problem is that it doesn't use it, or clang-format at all

Comment: is root of your checkout the same directory where the project file resides?

Comment: Yes, it is. However, from all I read this configuration should always use clang-format even when not . clang-format available

Comment: you probably already tried renaming it to '_clang-format'? Worst case is reinstall Visual Studio. I had some problems with git and IntelliSense and the only way was reinstalling.

Comment: Again, the config above should use clang-format regardless of a config file. So no, haven't tried that

Comment: I've tried renaming, doesn't change anything

Comment: Do you have installed any extensions that could conflict with clang-format?

Comment: None that I haven't tried disabling, except for the productivity power tools.

Comment: Mhm I am sorry I couldn't help!

Comment: @JVApen, I use 15.9.11 and it works for me, i.e. uses .clang-format file.  The only difference in the config(other than using custom clang exe) is that `Default formatting style` is set to `Visual Studio` instead of `Google`.

Comment: Another silly assumption.  Is it possible that there's another nested `.clang-format` in the repo?  So that it is preferred over the `.clang-format` in root folder.

Comment: Another _"most likely 'yes', but let's double check this"_-question: are the file (its extension) you're aiming to format associated with C/C++ mode?

Comment: Yes, files which nicely end and .cpp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strangely enough, this started to work without any extra changes after a couple of days.

Comment: Ctrl+K+D works, but formatting while typing is horribly broken - it constantly keeps getting confused between regular VS editor settings and clang options.

Comment: I don't see added value in an extension if there is standard support. I haven't checked the extension for the formatting, though, it does require the compile_database or the visual studio build system for the other functionalities. (Which unfortunately doesn't work in this case, something I should look into)

Comment: Not strangely enough actually, it's a microsoft product.

Comment: Hi @JVApen, do you have installed the clang compiler or checked any clang related options in VS installer ? I can't manage to make my .clang-format work neither, and i wanted to DL clang-format exe itself, but it seems that i have to DL the whole clang suite to get it, and i really don't want to DL gygabytes of unused stuff just for that. Thanks for any tips i could try to make that works, hopefully in 2-3 days it will start working like you :D

Comment: I do believe it was installed. If you only want clang-format, install from the llvm installer. You can copy the exe to another location and uninstall everything again

Comment: I noticed Visual Studio doesn't accepts .clang-format if it is a json file, it needs to be a yaml file.

Comment: Most likely it still uses an old version