# How to prettify C++ in VS Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, format, clang-format

I am writing some C++ code inside my text editor VS Code.

So at some point, the code became hard to format/prettify the code manually.

I tried to use "format document",

 But nothing happened, even with the C/C++ extension active.

---

I want something like Prettier extension but for C++, is it possible?

---

- Is it possible that it follows almost the same principles/config of prettier (prettier only works in Javascript)?

---

*note that:*

- I am using all sorts of capabilities of C++ like:

  - classes
  - templates
  - namespace
  - variables
  - includes
  - loops
  - pointers

Comment: I bookmarked this for Visual Studio Community. I have wanted to modify a few behaviors of the default formatting (that drive me nuts) for years but I haven't got around to learning.. I found this question to help get started: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55781685/how-to-get-clang-format-working-in-visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55781685/how-to-get-clang-format-working-in-visual-studio)

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-ide look for clang format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You maybe searching about **clang-format**

### Instructions (VS Code)

1. install C/C++ extension *(if you don't have it)*
2. create a file called `.clang-format`

> Preferably should be inside the same directory as the C++ file

4. copy and paste this code inside that file

```yaml
---

Language: Cpp

DisableFormat: false
RemoveSemicolon: false
RemoveBracesLLVM: false
SpaceInEmptyBlock: false
CompactNamespaces: false
SpaceBeforeCaseColon: false
SpaceAfterLogicalNot: false
SpaceBeforeSquareBrackets: false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: false
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false

InsertBraces: true
ReflowComments: true
IndentRequires: true
IndentCaseLabels: true
BreakStringLiterals: true
FixNamespaceComments: true
IndentRequiresClause: true
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: true
IndentAccessModifiers: true
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: true
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: true
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: true
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: true
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: true 
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: true

SortIncludes: CaseInsensitive
IncludeBlocks: Regroup
AlignOperands: AlignAfterOperator 
SpaceBeforeParens: Custom
RemoveParentheses: MultipleParentheses
IndentPPDirectives: AfterHash
NamespaceIndentation: All
BreakInheritanceList: AfterComma
SortUsingDeclarations: LexicographicNumeric
SpaceAroundPointerQualifiers: After
RequiresExpressionIndentation: Keyword
EmptyLineBeforeAccessModifier: LogicalBlock
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: Inline 
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: AllIfsAndElse 

AlignConsecutiveBitFields: Consecutive
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: Consecutive
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: Consecutive

PointerAlignment: Right
QualifierAlignment: Left
ReferenceAlignment: Right
AlignArrayOfStructures: Right 

UseTab: Never
SpacesInAngles: Never
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
EmptyLineAfterAccessModifier: Never

SeparateDefinitionBlocks: Always
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Always

IndentWidth: 2
ShortNamespaceLines: 0
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
ContinuationIndentWidth: 2
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1

ColumnLimit: 60

SpaceBeforeParensOptions:
  AfterPlacementOperator: false    
  AfterFunctionDefinitionName: false
  AfterFunctionDeclarationName: false
  AfterControlStatements: true

BraceWrapping:
  AfterEnum: false
  AfterClass: false
  AfterUnion: false
  BeforeElse: false
  BeforeWhile: false
  AfterStruct: false
  BeforeCatch: false
  AfterFunction: false
  AfterCaseLabel: false
  AfterNamespace: false
  AfterExternBlock: false
  SplitEmptyRecord: false
  SplitEmptyFunction: false
  SplitEmptyNamespace: false
  AfterControlStatement: Never

AlignConsecutiveShortCaseStatements:
  Enabled: true 
  AcrossComments: true 
  AlignCaseColons: true 
  AcrossEmptyLines: true 

AlignTrailingComments: 
  Kind: Always
  OverEmptyLines: 2

---
```

- now finally it should work when you use "format document",
- or you need to follow these docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-ide#_code-formatting
- if nothing works then install the `Clang-Format` extension

  - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xaver.clang-format

---

since you told me that you want code that is formatted similarly to the configs of Prettier (that it used in js instead),

I tried, and here are some of the main advantages:

### Configs inspired by Prettier

1. positioning of brackets `{` and `}`

```cpp
/* bad */
void foo(int bar)
{
int a;
}

/* good */
void foo(int bar) {
  int a;
};
```

2. line length and wrapping

```cpp
/* bad */
bool arr[] = { true, true, true, false, true, false, true, true, false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, false, false, true, true };

/* good */
bool arr[] = {
    false, false, true, true, true, true, true,
    true,  true,  true, true, true, true, true};
```

3. namespace nesting

```cpp
/* bad */
namespace Base 
{
class MyClass 
{
}
}

/* good */
namespace Base {
  class MyClass {};
}; // namespace Base
```

4. class nesting

```cpp
/* bad */
class MyClass {
private:
int a;
int b;
public:
int c;
void bar() {};
}

/* good */
class MyClass {
  private:
    int a;
    int b;
  public:
    int c;
    void bar() {};
}
```

4. short loops/statements written in only one line.

```cpp
/* bad */
while(condition) {
  i++;
}

/* good */
while(condition) { i++; };
```

5. consecutive variables prettified

```cpp
/* bad */
int a = 10;
double b = 20;
long c = 30;
char d = "a"
int efg = 40;

/* good */
int    a   = 10;
double b   = 20;
long   c   = 30;
char   d   = "a"
int    efg = 40;
```

6. pointers

```cpp
/* bad */
int* a;
int* b, * c, * d;

/* good */
int *a;
int *b, *c, *d;
```

7. space instead of tabs
8. semicolons everywhere C++ needs.
9. remove useless empty spaces

```cpp
/* bad */
void foo(int bar) {
  std::cout << bar << std::endl;




  std::cout << 123 << std::endl;
};

/* good */
void foo(int bar) {
  std::cout << bar << std::endl;

  std::cout << 123 << std::endl;
};
```

10. nested arrays formatting

```cpp
/* bad */
int foo[3][3] = {{1,2,33},{444,5555,6},{7,88,99999}};

/* good */
int foo[3][3] = {
  {  1,    2,    33},
  {444, 5555,     6},
  {  7,   88, 99999},
};
```

and much more, and you can even customize it,

 by following these docs: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

try it, and hopefully it will solve your problem!

Comment: I don't think a separate extension for clang-format is required.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-ide#_code-formatting And the documentation states that clang-format is included with the extension.

Comment: CppFormatClangConfig is terrible and long - most of values are default. You should start it with `BasedOnStyle` and maybe only modify a tiny set of the style settings from their defaults.

Comment: @sweenish you are right, but for making it the most simple way for new users, the extension works well (also to remove the error "there is no formatted for 'cpp' files installed")

Comment: All that's required is the Microsoft C++ extension, and a `.clang-format` file in the repo root to specify the desired style (and that's only if a default isn't cutting it). I would link to the official clang-format documentation instead of a random Github repo.

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas "For making it the most simple" give them the least amount of steps. They only need one extension, and to configure it. That's easier than multiple extensions, and a random repo that instills bad practices. The link I provided to official documentation is quite simple.

Comment: And I'm only just catching on to the fact that you're answering your own question. I certainly appreciate the desire to help others, but this guide is giving bad advice.

Comment: @sweenish updated the answer, tell me if is right